# Physical location of "Style Library"

Tags: css

I'm a complete newbie in sharepoint so this is an easy question.

I've uploaded a .css to the Style Library and am looking for an easy way to change it. (ctrl+s to save and F5 to refresh page)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an upload using the web interface or SP designer, it does not have a physical location. It is stored in the database.

You could initially deploy your file into the Style Library using a "Feature" instead, which means you will have a physical file on the filesystem in your Feature folder. You can use this file to repeatedly perform your edit/save/refresh sequence with no delays.

Note that as soon as you modify/overwrite this file through the web interface or SP designer, you lose the ability to change the file on the filesystem and see it's changes.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaap Vossers - The method you describes do not work. At least not in MOSS 2007. There you had to manually delete the file from the Style Library and then reactivate the feature to get an updated file. Maybe this has changed in 2010?

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: @JWL I have no trouble getting it to work in MOSS2007, it's not new in SP2010

Comment: @Jaap Vossers - What kind of dark magic do you have in your elements xml? :)

Comment: It's called CAML :p